# How to declare two dimensional array accessible from other functions?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a quick Question:

If I want to have a two dimensional array accessible from other functions, should I define it as a static ? and If so, How can I initialize it using other members.
 Here is my code:

```
private:
    static double Q [][];
};
```

This is the part that uses the array Q in function called firstpassagetime:

```
HGlycation A1C;
int states = A1C.    
Q [states][states];
for ( int k = 0; k < states; k++)
{
    if ( k != j)
    {
        currenti =k;
        return (sum + ( Q[i][k]*firstpassagetime( k,j, n-1)));
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Full Code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class HGlycation
{
    public:
    double method1 (double L []); // based on the first-passage-time probabilities.
    double firstpassagetime(int i, int j, int n);
    private:
    int Numberofstates ;
    int g, c ; // model paramteres.
    static  double L[];
    static std:: double Q[][100];

};

//Q[100][100];


double HGlycation::method1 ( double L [])
{

    HGlycation A1C;
    int states = A1C.Numberofstates;
    for ( int i = 0; i < states;i++)
    {
        L[i] = i % states;

    }

    //A1C.Q [states][100];  // mine
    double P [states][states];  // get it from luise functions

    for ( int i =0 ; i < states; i++)
    {

        for (int j=0;j< states; j++)
        {
            if ( i==0 && j==0)
                Q[i][j]==1;
            else if ( i == 0 && j!=0)
                Q[i][j]=0;
            else if( i !=0 && j ==0)
                Q[i][j]= g*L[i] +c;
            else
                Q[i][j]= (1- (g*L[i]+c))* P[i][j];
            \\ the rest of the code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on what context you're using the array in.  Is it "global" for a class?  Make it static.  Is it "local" to a specific object?  Then don't make it static.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do something like. You should always use std::vector or std::array over plain C arrays.

```
#include <vector>

struct A{
private:
    static std::vector<std::vector<double>> Q;

    static std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec_init(){
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> temp(100);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            Q[i] = std::vector<double>(100,0);
        }
        return temp;
     }
 };


 std::vector<std::vector<double>> A::Q = A::vec_init();

 int main(){
     //Would print but its private
     return 0;
 }
```

This will create a 100x100 grid of zero initialized doubles.

EDIT: Even better!

```
struct A {
private:
   static std::vector<std::vector<double>> Q;
};

std::vector<std::vector<double>> A::Q(100, std::vector<double>(100,0));

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shorter version of init, `std::vector<std::vector<double>> A::Q(100, 100);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb That didn't work but: `std::vector<std::vector<double>>(100, std::vector<double>(100));` did.

Comment: Ah. I see now that my version doesn't work because the `vector(size_type n)` constructor is `explicit`.

Comment: Sam, you need to learn the concepts, you can't just post questions all over the net having people code your program for you. Instead of asking "Will this work, run it. At first I tried to help out, but people on here are more concerned with trying to show off to other posters while completely disregarding the knowledge base of the op, which in this case is way under knowing what a Vector or List, etc.. is